# Uniform convex space

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Please I want to know if this space

$$H^1_{0,p}([0,+\infty))=\lbrace u, u\in AC([0,+\infty)), u(0)=u(+\infty)=0,\sqrt{p}u'\in L^2\rbrace$$

where $p>0$, $p\in L^1((0,+\infty))$

$$||u||^2=\int_0^{+\infty} p(t) (u'(t))^2 dt $$

is uniformly convex ?

Please

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\newcommand{\inner}[2]{\langle #1 \mspace{-3mu}\mid\mspace{-3mu} #2\rangle}$

$$\inner{u}{v} = \int_0^\infty u'(t)v'(t)p(t)\,dt.\tag{1}$$

$\inner{\cdot}{\cdot}$ is a bilinear form, and $\inner{u}{u} = \lVert u\rVert^2$ is zero only for $u \equiv 0$. Hence $\inner{\cdot}{\cdot}$ is an inner product inducing the norm.

Every space whose norm is induced by an inner product is uniformly convex, since the parallelogram identity

$$\lVert u+v\rVert^2 + \lVert u-v\rVert^2 = 2\lVert u\rVert^2 + 2\lVert v\rVert^2\tag{2}$$

holds. If we take $\lVert u\rVert = \lVert v\rVert = 1$ in $(2)$, we find

$$\left\lVert \tfrac{1}{2}(u+v)\right\rVert = \sqrt{1 - \left\lVert\tfrac{1}{2}(u-v)\right\rVert^2},$$

which shows the uniform convexity.

For the (equivalent) definition of uniform convexity where $\lVert u\rVert,\lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1$ is the criterion, note that then

$$\left\lVert\tfrac{1}{2}(u+v)\right\rVert = \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(\lVert u\rVert^2 + \lVert v\rVert^2) - \left\lVert\tfrac{1}{2}(u-v)\right\rVert^2} \leqslant \sqrt{1 - \left\lVert\tfrac{1}{2}(u-v)\right\rVert^2},$$

so $\lVert u\rVert,\lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1$ and $\lVert u-v\rVert \geqslant \varepsilon$ implies

$$\left\lVert\tfrac{1}{2}(u+v)\right\rVert \leqslant \sqrt{1-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}}.$$

Comment: Please why we take ||u||=||v||=1 please

Comment: I tried to apply this definition but i don't lnow how we choose $\delta$: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_uniform%C3%A9ment_convexe#D.C3.A9finition

Comment: It doesn't matter if we take $\lVert x\rVert, \lVert y\rVert$ both $= 1$ or $\leqslant 1$, the definitions are equivalent. [The English wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space) uses $= 1$, and that's in my experience the more common definition. Nevertheless, I'll add the inequality for $\leqslant 1$. One or two minutes.

Comment: And what is $\delta$

Comment: $$\delta = 1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}}.$$

Comment: we need a condition on $\varepsilon$ such that $1-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}>0$ and $\delta>0$

Comment: $\varepsilon < 2$ guarantees $1-\frac{\varepsilon^2}{4} > 0$. But if $\varepsilon \geqslant 2$, then $\lVert u-v\rVert > \varepsilon$ is impossible for $\lVert u\rVert,\lVert v\rVert \leqslant 1$, and then the condition is vacuously satisfied, so for $\varepsilon\geqslant 2$, any $\delta$ fulfills the condition.